# Why $f(x) = 0$ is not excluded from the codomain?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Here is the question I am trying to solve (I already solved):

Suppose $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is a continuously differentiable function and

$\bullet f(0) =1$.

$\bullet f'(x) \leq \frac{-1}{2} f(x)$ for all $x \geq 0.$

Prove that $f(x) \leq e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$ for $x\geq 0.$

**My question is:**

I managed to prove the statement after integrating both sides  of $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \leq \frac{-1}{2},$$(from $0$ to $x$) ,  for all $x \geq 0,$ but the thing is how can I be sure that $f(x) \neq 0$?

Also, is integrating from $0$ to $x$ correct?

Could someone help me answer this question please?

Comment: Rewrite it as a 1st-order linear ODE, then solve the ODE using an integrating factor (just use the inequality where you would normally use an equal sign).

Comment: Regardless of the better method pointed out by **The Substitute** the case $f(x)=0$ or even $f(x)\le 0$ can be omitted since the thesis $f(x)\le e^{-x/2}$ is obviously fulfilled.

Comment: For the record, you can't be sure that $f(x)\ne 0$, because it's false. The function $f(x)=\begin{cases}e\cdot e^{(x-1)^{-1}}&\text{if }x<1\\ 0&\text{if }x\ge 1\end{cases}$ is $C^\infty$ and it satisfies the two conditions. Specifically, $$f'(x)+\frac12f(x)=\begin{cases}e\left(\frac12-(x-1)^{-2}\right)e^{(x-1)^{-1}}&\text{if }x<1\\ 0&\text{if }x\ge1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @TheSubstitute what will be the integrating factor in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first step of dividing by $f(x)$ is fraught: As you're aware, if $f(x) = 0$ we'd be dividing by $0$, but worse if $f(x) < 0$ the inequality gets flipped.

Instead, it's cleaner to introduce the function $g(x) = e^{x/2}f(x)$, and use the product rule and $f'(x) \leq -\frac{1}{2}f(x)$ to show $g'(x) \leq 0$ for all non-negative $x$. The mean value theorem together with $g(0) = 1$ then guarantees $g(x) \leq 1$ for all non-negative $x$.

Comment: Absolutely: the MVT is the way to go. (Especially for those who meet this sort of problem before they have done any rigorous integration).

Comment: @ancientmathematician can you please show me this method?

Comment: I understood your first paragraph, but I did not understand the second paragraph can you provide the details please?  ..... the think is that I was advised to solve it by Cauchy Schwartz inequality that is why I divided by $f(x)$

Comment: I think I understood your second paragraph just now, let me try to write it

Comment: I am a little bit confused on how to apply the MVT, where is my interval $[a,b]$ in our case here? I think it is $[0, \infty)$ but how can the point $b = \infty$ in the MVT?

Comment: And so I did not get how you got that $g(x) \leq 1$ then. Could you clarify please?